# getting "undefined" after assigning fetched data to React state

Tags: json, reactjs, api, state, undefined

Here is my state:

```
this.state = {
      questionArr: [],
      diceRoll: 0,
      category: "category",
      currentQuestion: "click to get a new flashcard.",
      correctAnswer: undefined,
      details: "Use this app to test your network+ knowledge",
      choice1: "choice one",
      choice2: "choice two",
      choice3: "choice three",
      choice4: "choice four",
      success: "black",
      scorable: true,
      score: 0
    };
```

I'm trying to fetch the data and assign it to the questionArr.

to do that I'm using the following code:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    const {questionArr} = this.state;
    
    fetch(API).then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
      this.setState({
      questionArr : res.questions
      })
    });
    
  }
```

for some reason, if I replace the this.setState with `alert(res.questions[0]["q"])` it has no problem doing the alert and displaying the first question in the array. But, If I try to do an alert with questionArr as it is written up there, it comes out as undefined, like this: `alert(questionArr[0])`.

Here is an example of what I'd like to do with this questionArr. Basically I just want to know that I actually have the information and use it in other functions for presenting random quiz questions. But, for example, if I tried to render the information onto the screen as in the following code, the whole screen will just go blank and nothing with render at all (on codepen.io).

```
render() {
    
    const { diceRoll, category, currentQuestion, correctAnswer, details, choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4, success, scorable, score, questionArr} = this.state;
    
    
    return(
    <div className = "main">
        <div className = "scoreBoard">
          {score}
          {questionArr[0]["q"]}
        </div>
```

this is the link to the json file I uploaded to github: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DPodrasky/net-plus-test-questions/main/questions.json

this is the Json file I uploaded to github:

```
{
"questions" :[
 {
   "cat": "Windows Name Resolution",
   "q": "What does nbtstat -R do?",
   "a": "nbtstat -R purges the remote cache table.",
   "a1": "Nbtstat -R shows network records.",
   "a2": "It removes nbtstat from your computer",
   "a3": "It remembers your last nbtstat command for later use.",
   "a4": "nbtstat -R purges the remote cache table.",
   "details": ""
 } ,
  {
   "cat": "Windows Name Resolution",
    "q": "What does nbtstat -RR do?",
    "a": "nbtstat -RR rebroadcasts all of your registered info and re-establishes those communications.",
    "a1": "Nbtstat -R shows network records.",
   "a2": "It removes nbtstat from your computer",
   "a3": "It remembers your last nbtstat command for later use.",
   "a4": "nbtstat -R purges the remote cache table.",
    "details": ""
 },
  {
    "cat": "Windows Name Resolution",
    "q": "What is a registered name?",
    "a": "A registered name is a non-duplicated name that is only registered to that specific system.",
    "a1": "Nbtstat -R shows network records.",
   "a2": "It removes nbtstat from your computer",
   "a3": "It remembers your last nbtstat command for later use.",
   "a4": "nbtstat -R purges the remote cache table.",
    "details": ""
  },
  {
    "cat": "Windows Name Resolution",
    "q": "How can you find your system's registered name?",
    "a": "nbtstat -n will produce your system's registered name, group, and functionality.",
    "a1": "Nbtstat -R shows network records.",
   "a2": "It removes nbtstat from your computer",
   "a3": "It remembers your last nbtstat command for later use.",
   "a4": "nbtstat -R purges the remote cache table.",
    "details": ""
  },
  {
    "cat": "Windows Name Resolution",
    "q": "What does --MSBrowse-- surrounded by two smiley emojis mean?",
    "a":"It means that computer is the browser manager.",
    "a1": "Nbtstat -R shows network records.",
   "a2": "It removes nbtstat from your computer",
   "a3": "It remembers your last nbtstat command for later use.",
   "a4": "nbtstat -R purges the remote cache table.",
    "details": ""
  },
  {
    "cat": "Windows Name Resolution",
    "q": "What is nbtstat?",
    "a": "It's a good tool for troubleshooting network issues.",
    "a1": "It's a pill for high blood pressure.",
    "a2": "It's a good tool for troubleshooting network issues.",
    "a3": "It's a tool the always works well with LLMNR",
    "a4": "It's a network t/s tool that does not have any obsolete commands. All of its commmands work perfectly.",
    "details": "It does not work well with LLMNR. Many commands don't work anymore or are useless."
  }
  
]
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to get from deconstructing the `const { questionArr } = this.state` inside `componentDidMount`, it's still an empty array at that time, and the fetch will only fill it after it passed through the full fetch state. Meaning, upon first render of your component the `this.state.questionArr` will indeed be an empty array as defined in your constructor. You don't really show where you are calling the `this.state.questionArr` afterwards, so I assume you intend to use the one you destructed (which will always be empty)

Comment: Also `setState` does not immediately apply. But to get a better answer it would be good if you amended you above code sample to show when exactly you perform the logging.

Comment: Ok, I added a small snipped of the first part of the render method to show an example of something simple I'd like to do with the json data, displaying it on the screen. Once I know that I have the data and can use it, I will incorporate it into the functions that handle the random choosing of the quesitions. Currently, this app runs of an array that is coded directly in the JS, which I want to replace with the json file, instead.

Comment: yeah, so inside your first render, your data is simply not there yet, just verify if the array has a length of 0 and `return null`, the next `setState` will cause a re-render, and your'll be rendering your data ;)

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. Thanks for the effort, guys. basically, I can still use the fetch and apply res.questions to my state variable, questionsArr. All I needed to do was just trust that the information was there and use questionsArr in the function that pulls the random flashcard and it worked as I was hoping it would.

Answer (score 0):

After going back to look at it, I found that the fetch was successful, but I just needed to use the information in the function that displays the next flashcard. So, fetching API info (in this case just a JSON file) during componentDidMount and storing that information in a state variable was actually successful.

It turns out that all I had to do was then use that variable in the function that displays the next flashcard and it would work as expected. I was trying to do simple tests immediately with the fetch function and it wasn't working as I thought it would. Basically, I just needed to use the state variable in a function after the componentDidMount and fetch stored the variable into that state variable.